# Egit installed but not showing

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, eclipse-luna

Good day everyone. I'm using Eclipse Luna and trying to use EGit tools but, it isn't working anymore.

I only see apply patch in the "team" option:

[image: Apply patch]

Import -> git projects isn't showing as well :

[image]

I checked preferences, and I didn't see git as well

[image: preferences]

I tried to switch workspace, running eclipse with -clean parameter, but it didn't help. I also checked if egit and jgit are installed, and they're installed:

[image]

I checked the error Log and I found something:

[image: Error Log]

I hope someone can help me "restore" the Git thingy. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with Mars?

Comment: nope.  I just reinstalled eclipse. :(

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem in Mars. Seems to have started after I updated to egit 4.1. I tried downgrading to 4.0.3 without success. Did reinstalling eclipse solve the problem?

Comment: What is the exact error message in your log? It may hint on the cause.

Comment: @RangiKeen , yes, I just reinstalled eclipse and downloaded all the softwre again (I didn't download egit but I still got it )

Comment: I just updated to Mars 4.5.1 and the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Windows -> Preferences -> General - Capabilities

Then click the ADVANCED button and you should see the GIT not marked

Answer (score -1):

Why installing Git? All Eclipse 4.x versions do come with EGit already installed.

Comment: Egit is not up to date in Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Eclipse will not run an external GIT, only EGIT it comes with.

Comment: I've got the same issue with a fresh install of STS version. Egit is installed, but it does not  show up where I would expect in the Project Explorer, the way I would usually commit changes or switch branches.